# What string is at the top of the stack and what string is at the bottom of the stack

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

Using the following 5 different methods contained in the interface:

add(newEntry) : Adds a new entry to the back of the queue

remove()      : Removes and returns the queue’s front entry

peek()        : Retrieves the queue’s top entry without changing the queue

---

Queue myQueue = new LinkedList();

```
myQueue.add( “Jane” ); 
myQueue.add( “Jess” ); 
myQueue.add( “Jill” ); 
myQueue.add( myQueue.remove()); 
myQueue.add( myQueue.peek()); 
myQueue.add( “Jim” ); 
String name = myQueue.remove(); 
myQueue.add( myQueue.peek());
```

I'm expecting the items to be ordered like this:

TOP/FRONT

Jill

Jane

Jess

Jim

Jill

BOTTOM/BACK

Comment: What's stopping you from testing it? Also, why do you use a LinkedList, when the title talks about Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and everything was ok.

at first, the queue is like this

```
 Jane -> Jess -> Jill
```

then we remove the top, and then add it to bottom

```
 jesss -> jill -> jane
```

then we add the top to bottom

```
 jess -> jill ->jane -> jess
```

then we add jim to bottom

```
 jess -> jill ->jane -> jess -> jim
```

then we remove the top

```
 jill ->jane -> jess -> jim
```

then we add the top to bottom

```
 jill ->jane -> jess -> jim -> jill
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question's title is about a Stack but your question's content is about a Queue implementation using a LinkedList. Both Stack and Queue are different data structures and work differently. Assuming you mean a Queue, the correct order after these operations would be

Jill -> Jane -> Jess -> Jim -> Jill

**Operation 1**
Add Jill

```
Queue becomes - Jane
```

**Operation 2**
Add Jess

```
Queue becomes - Jane -> Jess
```

**Operation 3**
Add Jill

```
Queue becomes - Jane -> Jess -> Jill
```

**Operation 4**
Remove first element from Queue and add it to the end

```
Queue becomes - Jess -> Jill -> Jane
```

**Operation 5**
Add the first element to the queue again

```
Queue becomes - Jess -> Jill -> Jane -> Jess
```

**Operation 6**
Add Jim

```
Queue becomes - Jess -> Jill -> Jane -> Jess -> Jim
```

**Operation 7**
Remove first element

```
Queue becomes -Jill -> Jane -> Jess -> Jim
```

**Operation 8**
Add the first element to the queue again

```
Queue becomes - Jill -> Jane -> Jess -> Jim -> Jill
```

Comment: your answer is wrong at operation 5. after we remove jane from top then we add this to the bottom.so the queue is like jess-> jill -> jane